# Logcat Throws errors when overlaying a Fragment with a SurfaceHolder

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, surfaceholder

I am trying to overlay a`fragment` with `cameraPreview` instance. The root of the `fragment` layout has a xml tag `<surfaceview`. When I run the App it crashes and throws the below errors. any idea why that happens?

Class_Extends_Fragment:

```
    public class CameraPreviewFragment extends Fragment {

private CustomCameraView mCameraPreview = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mCameraPreview = new CustomCameraView(this.getActivity());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camerapreviewfragment, null);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    SurfaceView sv = (SurfaceView) getView().findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

}
```

MainActivity_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.fragmentwithcamerasurface.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">
    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.fragmentwithcamerasurface.CameraPreviewFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment00ID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </fragment>
```

fragmentRoot_layout:

```
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
android:background="#ffff00">

<!--logcat complains about this line-->
    <com.example.fragmentwithcamerasurface.CustomCameraView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

logCat:

```
 05-28 09:34:13.670: E/AndroidRuntime(11327): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to  
 start activity   
 ainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error  
 inflating class com.example.fragmentwithcamerasurface.CustomCameraView
 05-28 09:34:13.670: E/AndroidRuntime(11327): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to 
 start activity  
 ainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error   
 inflating class com.example.fragmentwithcamerasurface.CustomCameraView
 05-28 09:34:13.670: E/AndroidRuntime(11327):   at
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong layout file as your fragment's root layout.  The layout file you inflate in getView() should be the file specifying the views you want to see *inside* the fragment, not the fragment itself.

I believe the layout inflater only goes 25 steps deep recursively.

---

You should add `false` as a third argument to `LayoutInflater.inflate`.

And `CameraPreviewFragment` is not a `Context`.

Comment: ok, if `CameraPreviewFragment` has no context, and to instantiate an object from a class that extends surfaceholder you should provide a context, how can this be solved?

Comment: @Amr no no, look at my first sentence.

Comment: ok, i modified it to be "View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camerapreviewfragment, null, false);" but unfoortunately the same error

Comment: Post your fragment's layout file then.

Comment: please see both of fragment_root and mainActivtiy_layout are posted above

Answer (score 0):

First of all inflating with R.layout.camerapreviewfragment but the layout you are creating is fragmentRoot_layout and

```
tools:context="com.example.fragmentwithcamerasurface.CameraPreviewFragment"
```

CameraPreviewFragment is not a context

Hey checkout [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes#TOC-tools%3acontext%3E) for details about tools:context

Comment: when i added the line "tools:context.." i thought it is important. but knw ideleted it as you suggested but i receive the same error! would you please tell me when this line "tools:context.." is useful?

Comment: The `tools:context` line is not the culprit.  @Troopers you literally copy-pasted my answer.

Comment: @dcow FYI the moment I opened the question in an another tab that time there was no answer for this so I answered the question without checking out your answer.....and also now you have edited about the layout file so :D .....

Comment: Had that before you too (;